# Should not the "Low Quality Posts," and "Suggested Edits" link for the Reviewer badge take to the site for which the badge has been gained?

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, review, notifications

The notifications for the Reviewer badge contains a link to the review page for which the badge has been gained, but that link takes to the review page for the site where the SuperDropdown menu is being viewed.

Should not those links take to the site where the badge has been gained? Alternatively, there should not be any link to the review pages.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should now be fixed - thanks for the report!